# Binary XML file line #12 Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: java, android, xml, crash

I`ve been trying to run my app (android) but it crashes every time I summon the second activity, I have the main activity named MainActivity.java, and the second one is Game.java, the XML files are the same name as the activitys.

The XML code that crashes:

[XML](http://pastebin.com/TJ1tMAfN)

[Game.java](http://pastebin.com/sE93mwjs)

I know I did some stupid things in the OnCreate method, but ignore it please
I really need help I don`t know what I`ve done wrong !

Comment: can you post error log here?

Comment: Do you have `game.xml` in `res/menu` folder?

Comment: 1.I do have game.xml in res/menu foler.

Comment: Error log :http://pastebin.com/KjrrT1iF

Comment: The error you have mentioned in the title of the post isn't even there in the `Error log`.

Comment: The error shows up in the Log Cat window. the error log is different. I`ll post the log cat :http://pastebin.com/LKkTjsMT

Comment: So, remove this line `style="@style/AppTheme"` from all the buttons. All properties need to be accessed as `android:propertyName="propertyValue"`. And `android:style` is not a valid property for `android.Widget.Button`. Also, `android:background="@style/AppTheme"` can cause problem. You are better off removing all instances of this as well. Search on google how to style buttons in android. You'll find plenty of information.

Comment: The problem is solved ! Thank you very much